# Discord js Slash command with embed ReferenceError: interaction is not define

Tags: javascript, discord.js, command, slash

"title": `${interaction.user.username}'s Profile`
ReferenceError: interaction is not defined

```js
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');
const { EmbedBuilder } = require('discord.js');

const profileEmbed = {
    "type": "rich",
    "color": 0x00fff0,
    "title": `${interaction.user.username}'s Profile`
    "avatar": ?
                
}

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('profile')
        .setDescription('Replies with your profile!'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply({embeds: [profileEmbed]});
    },
};
```

Is there a way that I can use interactions in "title" and with "avatar" aswell? I get "interaction is not defined" error when I run node deploy-commands.js file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always turn the `profileEmbed` object into a function that returns the object, and just pass in the interaction.

```
function profileEmbed(interaction) {
  return {
    "type": "rich",
    "color": 0x00fff0,
    "title": `${interaction.user.username}'s Profile`
    "avatar": ?   
  }
}
```

```
await interaction.reply({embeds: [profileEmbed(interaction)]})
```

This may not be what you're looking for in terms of style, but it should accomplish what you're trying to do.